# How do I put some space over and under my header and footer pictures?

Tags: graphics, header-footer, eso-pic

So, I want a picture in my page headers, and one in my footer. This is the code I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for lipsum text
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\AtPageUpperLeft{\raisebox{-\height}{\hspace{105pt}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}}%
}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\AtPageLowerLeft{\hspace{445pt}\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm]{example-image-b}}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, there is no margin above and below the pictures:

[image: Header]

[image: Footer]

How can I remedy this? Bonus point for showing an alternative to my awful `hspace` solution!

Comment: ...bonus points? But how? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) in `oneside` mode, the left-margin space should be given by `\spinemargin`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for lipsum text
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height-5pt}{\hspace{\spinemargin}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}%
  }
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \raisebox{12pt}{%
      \hspace{\dimexpr\spinemargin+\textwidth}\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm]{example-image-b}}%
    }
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Above I've dropped (negative raise) the header image by an additional `5pt` and raised the footer image by `12pt`. You can adjust this as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the header and footer commands of the memoir class?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\topmargin\dimexpr-1in+1em\headheight3cm\headsep1em\footskip\dimexpr1.5cm+1em
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\headheight]{example-image-a}}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm]{example-image-b}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-17]
\end{document}
```

Or more accordingly to the memoir way:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setulmarginsandblock{4.5cm}{4cm}{*}
\setheadfoot{3cm}{1cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{2.5cm}
\checkandfixthelayout
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\headheight]{example-image-a}}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm]{example-image-b}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-17]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the value of the first argument of `\raisebox`
2. replace `\AtPageUpperLeft` with `\AtTextUpperLeft` to avoid using `\hspace` for the header.
3. for the footer: define a `\newlength{\footerhspace}` equal to `\textwidth` minus the picture width.

!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for lipsum text
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\footerhspace}
\setlength{\footerhspace}{\textwidth-1.5cm}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\AtTextUpperLeft{\raisebox{0.25\height}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}}%
}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\AtTextLowerLeft{\raisebox{-2\height}{\hspace{\footerhspace}\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm]{example-image-b}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]